# Error while installing aerospike-node client on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, error-handling, client, aerospike

I am trying to install aerospike-node client with npm on Ubuntu.

```
npm install aerospike
```

While installing I am getting ERROR like

```
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/aerospike.node
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
aerospike.target.mk:186: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/aerospike.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/aerospike.node] Error 1
rm binding_gyp_aerospike_client_c_target_run_scripts_aerospike_client_c_sh.intermediate
make: Leaving directory '/home/sys1095/NodeProjects/aerospike-test/node_modules/aerospike/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/sys1095/NodeProjects/aerospike-test/node_modules/aerospike
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN aerospike-test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "aerospike"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Environment :: node -v 6.10.0 ,node-gyp -v 3.4.0 ,npm -v 3.10.10.

I did check about this on aerospike github issues, But I didn't get anything(specific).
I thought the main problem starts here

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

I didn't get what it was.
Is problem with version of the node or anything regarding os(ubuntu) relating gcc compiler version.

Help me with this.

Comment: Did you try searching for the "main problem"? http://serverfault.com/questions/481859/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lz-but-libz-exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will post here what I did to get node.js working on Ubuntu 16.04 for my application from my scratch notes. Hopefully you can follow my steps, including my missteps!!!,  and figure out where you missed out.

==== So here it goes  ====

**Install node.js**
Install and test node.js client on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

https://nodejs.org/en/
Download and install latest recommended release for most users. 
node-v6.9.1-linux-x64.tar.xz

(Save the file to Downloads directory)

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ tar xvf node-v6.9.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

⇒ node-v6.9.1-linux-x64 directory with all node.js components.

```
$ sudo mv node-v6.9.1-linux-x64 /usr/local/nodejs
```

**Install Library Pre-requisistes**

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8 libssl-dev liblua5.1-dev
```

(fails to find libssl0.9.8 - ubuntu 16.04 uses libssl1.0.0)

Let us do one at a time:

`$sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-dev`   (<-- just need to do this)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-0-dev' instead of 'liblua5.1-dev'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  autotools-dev libltdl-dev libtool libtool-bin
Suggested packages:
  libtool-doc autoconf automaken gfortran | fortran95-compiler gcj-jdk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autotools-dev libltdl-dev liblua5.1-0-dev libtool libtool-bin
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
Need to get 594 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,180 kB of additional disk space will be used.

`$sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`  (see below, already installed)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.

`$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0`   (see below, already installed)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.

**Add the symlinks:**

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so /usr/lib/liblua.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.a /usr/lib/liblua.a
$ ls /usr/lib/liblua*
```

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Nov  2 13:17 /usr/lib/liblua.a -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Nov  2 13:17 /usr/lib/liblua.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so

**Install npm**

(If you don't have npm, you cannot install aerospike node.js client.)

```
$ npm install aerospike
```

The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install npm

```
$ sudo apt install npm
```

**Run Application**

($cd your_location/your_application/Node)
*modify package.json*.

is:

```
{
  "name": "xxx-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "aerospike": "^1.0.36",
    "inquirer": "^0.8.0"   <--- my app specific
  }
}
```

change: `"aerospike": "^2.0.0"`,

Then,
`$npm install inquirer --save-dev`  (inquirer is a command line i/o library for my app.)

```
$npm install aerospike --save-dev
```

It should update package.json to something like this:

```
$ more package.json
{
  "name": "xxx-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "aerospike": "^2.0.0",
    "inquirer": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aerospike": "^2.4.1",
    "inquirer": "^0.8.5"
  }
}
```

Running Node -- (my) app.js
In the appropriate sub-directory:

```
$which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
$nodejs app.js
```